# WPF does not execute the button's binding command in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I have the following xaml in a wpf C# application. I would like to bind the button to an `ICommand` in a view model. For some reason, the binding command does not execute.

```
    <UserControl x:Class="UI.View.CustomizationView"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                 xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:UI.ViewModel"
                 d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance viewModel:CustomizationViewModel,
                                                  IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
                 d:DesignHeight="300"
                 d:DesignWidth="300"
                 mc:Ignorable="d">
        <Grid>
            <Button Content="Update Options" Background="LightBlue" Command="{Binding UpdateCommand}"/>
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

Here is my ViewModel:

```
    public class CustomizationViewModel : UiViewModelBase
    {
        public ICommand UpdateCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (updateCommand == null)
                {
                    updateCommand = new RelayCommand(() => this.HandleUpdateCommand());
                }
                return updateCommand;
            }
            set => this.Set(ref this.updateCommand, value);
        }

        private void HandleUpdateCommand()
        {
            // Do something but this function is never called when button is clicked
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help explain why `HandleUpdateCommand()` is never called?

Comment: Did you assign an instance of the ViewModel to the View?

Comment: How do you do that? I thought binding DataContext in the xaml is enough.

Comment: I would be enough if you do ... but you did not

Comment: Could you please give a hint of how to do that? I have been searching for a solution.

Comment: <UserControl.DataContext><viewModel:CustomizationViewModel/></UserControl.DataContext>

Comment: In your XAML you set the **design** DataContext but that is only used for **design** time and not at runtime ;o)

Comment: Awesome. It works. Thank you Sir Rufo so much for the explanation. You wouldn't believe how many frustrating days I spent on it :)